# Case-Insensitive List Search

Tags: c#, list, search, case-insensitive

I have a list `testList` that contains a bunch of strings. I would like to add a new string into the `testList` only if it doesn't already exist in the list. Therefore, I need to do a case-insensitive search of the list and make it efficient. I can't use `Contains` because that doesn't take into account the casing. I also don't want to use `ToUpper/ToLower` for performance reasons. I came across this method, which works:

```
    if(testList.FindAll(x => x.IndexOf(keyword, 
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).Count > 0)
       Console.WriteLine("Found in list");
```

This works, but it also matches partial words. If the list contains "goat", I can't add "oat" because it claims that "oat" is already in the list. Is there a way to efficiently search lists in a case insensitive manner, where words have to match exactly? thanks

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Instead of String.IndexOf, use [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) to ensure you don't have partial matches. Also don't use FindAll as that goes through every element, use [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) (it stops on the first one it hits).

```
if(testList.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(keyword,  
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) != -1) 
    Console.WriteLine("Found in list");
```

Alternately use some LINQ methods (which also stops on the first one it hits)

```
if( testList.Any( s => s.Equals(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) )
    Console.WriteLine("found in list");
```

Comment: Just to add, in a few quick tests, it seems that the first method is around 50% faster. Maybe someone else can confirm/deny that.

Comment: As of .NET 2.0, this is now easily done - look at shaxby's answer below.

Comment: The Contains method shaxby's referencing (that has an overload that takes an IEqualityComparer) is part of LINQ, so it certainly hasn't been available since .NET 2.0. Just the StringComparer class has been around for a while. List<T> doesn't have that method, nor does ArrayList or StringCollection (things that he could have easily been referencing as his 'list').

Comment: Well, since I actually _needed_ the index, this was definitely the best answer for me.

Comment: The first solution should use `List<>.Exists(Predicate<>)` instance method. Also note that if the list contains `null` entries, this can blow up. In that case it is more safe to say `keyword.Equals(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` than `x.Equals(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` (if you can guarantee that the `keyword` is never null).

Comment: Side note... for arrays, you can use the static `Array.FindIndex(array, predicate)`.

Answer (score 552):

I realise this is an old post, but just in case anyone else is looking, you *can* use `Contains` by providing the case insensitive string equality comparer like so:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

if (testList.Contains(keyword, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Keyword Exists");
}
```

This has been available since .net 2.0 according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Definitely the best answer out here. :)

Comment: Enumerable<T>.Contains (what you're referencing) hasn't been around since .NET 2.0. There is no List<T>.Contains that has the overload you're using.

Comment: @AdamSills right. There is no such contains method in List<T>. And if it's a lazy collection, than it can iterate it a couple of times as other Enumerable<T> methods do. Imho, this method shouldn't be used for such cases, as it's not so logical for that case.

Comment: If your list happens to be sorted, you can use BinarySearch(string, IComparable<string>), which StringComparer implements.

Comment: I was not seeing this overload at first either, but you need to add using System.Linq then it appears.

Comment: @shaxby: You just ended my hours of head banging. Million thanks.

Comment: The `StringComparer` class has been around since 2.0, but that overload of Contains was introduced in 3.5.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was going to downvoting this answer because I was confusing StringComparer with StringComparison (that I use quite a lot in string.Equals (...) method). Don't make my mistake guys :)

Answer (score 25):

You can use `StringComparer` static variants with the `Contains` overload from LINQ for example, like this:

```cs
using System.Linq;

var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("cat");
list.Add("dog");
list.Add("moth");

if (list.Contains("MOTH", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("found");
}
```

Comment: As long as you add "using System.Linq", otherwise you won't see that overload for .Contains.

Answer (score 19):

Based on Adam Sills answer above - here's a nice clean extensions method for Contains... :)

```
///----------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the specified list contains the matching string value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">The list.</param>
/// <param name="value">The value to match.</param>
/// <param name="ignoreCase">if set to <c>true</c> the case is ignored.</param>
/// <returns>
///   <c>true</c> if the specified list contais the matching string; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </returns>
///----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static bool Contains(this List<string> list, string value, bool ignoreCase = false)
{
    return ignoreCase ?
        list.Any(s => s.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) :
        list.Contains(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Lance Larsen answer - here's an extension method with the recommended string.Compare instead of string.Equals

> It is highly recommended that you use an overload of String.Compare that takes a StringComparison parameter.   Not only do these overloads allow you to define the exact comparison behavior you intended, using them will also make your code more readable for other developers. [[Josh Free @ BCL Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/05/31/string-compare-string-equals-josh-free/)]

```
public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<string> source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    return
       source != null &&
       !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toCheck) &&
       source.Any(x => string.Compare(x, toCheck, comp) == 0);
}
```

Comment: I changed this slightly so that the first parameter is `this IEnumerable<string> source` to increase compatibility and allow better chaining with methods such as `.Where()`.

Comment: Thanks, adopted your improvement to the post

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the result of IndexOf is larger or equal 0, meaning whether the match starts **anywhere** in the string. Try checking if it's **equal** to 0:

```
if (testList.FindAll(x => x.IndexOf(keyword, 
                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).Count > 0)
   Console.WriteLine("Found in list");
```

Now "goat" and "oat" won't match, but "goat" and "goa" will. To avoid this, you can compare the lenghts of the two strings.

To avoid all this complication, you can use a dictionary instead of a list. They key would be the lowercase string, and the value would be the real string. This way, performance isn't hurt because you don't have to use `ToLower` for each comparison, but you can still use `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of searching for a keyword in the whole list and remove that item:

```
public class Book
{
  public int BookId { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Autor { get; set; }
  public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to remove a book that contains some keyword in the Text property, you can create a list of keywords and remove it from list of books:

```
List<Book> listToSearch = new List<Book>()
   {
        new Book(){
            BookId = 1,
            CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 27),
            Text = " test voprivreda...",
            Autor = "abc",
            Source = "SSSS"

        },
        new Book(){
            BookId = 2,
            CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 27),
            Text = "here you go...",
            Autor = "bcd",
            Source = "SSSS"


        }
    };

var blackList = new List<string>()
            {
                "test", "b"
            }; 

foreach (var itemtoremove in blackList)
    {
        listToSearch.RemoveAll(p => p.Source.ToLower().Contains(itemtoremove.ToLower()) || p.Source.ToLower().Contains(itemtoremove.ToLower()));
    }


return listToSearch.ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, I needed the index of the item but it had to be case insensitive, i looked around the web for a few minutes and found nothing, so I just wrote a small method to get it done, here is what I did:

```
private static int getCaseInvariantIndex(List<string> ItemsList, string searchItem)
{
    List<string> lowercaselist = new List<string>();

    foreach (string item in ItemsList)
    {
        lowercaselist.Add(item.ToLower());
    }

    return lowercaselist.IndexOf(searchItem.ToLower());
}
```

Add this code to the same file, and call it like this:

```
int index = getCaseInvariantIndexFromList(ListOfItems, itemToFind);
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: why produce a second list? That's not very efficient.

for(var i = 0; i < itemsList.Count; i++) {
if (item.ToLower() == searchItem.ToLower()) {
return i
}
}

Comment: I guess we will never know.