# Better code for avoiding one dictionary - Case Sensitivity Issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following method to fill a dictionary with values from a data reader.  There can be case mismatches between the data-reader fields and properties passed to the method. In the following method I  am converting the properties to lowercase first to address this issue. This causes two dictionaries. Is there a better way to achieve this with one dictionary?

```
private Dictionary<string, object> FillDictionaryWithReaderValues(List<string> propertiesOfAllEntities, IDataReader reader)
{
   Dictionary<string, object> lowerCaseDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   Dictionary<string, object> propertyResultList = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   foreach (var item in propertiesOfAllEntities)
   {
      lowerCaseDictionary.Add(item.ToLower(), null);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {
      lowerCaseDictionary[reader.GetName(i).ToLower()] = reader[i];
   }

   foreach (var item in propertiesOfAllEntities)
   {
      propertyResultList.Add(item, lowerCaseDictionary[item.ToLower()]);
   }

   return propertyResultList;
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that it can be refactored earlier. What are you actually doing here? The whole method might be redundant.

Comment: Why do you need 2 dictionaries? If you just stick to the convention that the key is always lowercase, you don't really need the other dictionary, right?

Comment: The case-insensitive-ness of the dictionary isn't really the issue here; it would let you remove the calls to `ToLower`, but won't stop you needing two dictionaries? (You'll still need to perform the don't-include-any-properties-that-were-in-the-reader-but-not-the-`propertyResultList` step, unless this isn't important.)

Comment: @Rawling Can't we use `List<string> propertiesOfAllEntities` for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CuongLe. Please upvote @Cuong Le answer if  you like the following.

For the benefit of others I will write the answer here:

```
    private Dictionary<string, object> FillDictionaryWithReaderValues(List<string> propertiesOfAllEntities, IDataReader reader)
    {

        Dictionary<string, object> propertyResultList = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            string readerFieldName = reader.GetName(i);
            //Whether propertiesOfAllEntities.Contains the property
            if (propertiesOfAllEntities.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(readerFieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1)
            {
                propertyResultList.Add(readerFieldName, reader[i]);
            }

        }

        return propertyResultList;
    }
```

REFERENCE:

1. [Case-Insensitive List Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947126/case-insensitive-list-search)

Answer (score 7):

You can ignore case in `Dictionary`, `Dictionary` has an [overload constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) which accepts `IEqualityComparer`, use `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to ignore case-sensitive for key:

```
var dic = 
      new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

So only one dictionary with ignore case is enough for your code