# How to avoid redundant List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Report object that has Recipients property (of String datatype). The Recipients property will hold all the recipients’ email address in `comma separated string`. I need to create a “**Collection**”  of Email objects from the comma separated string. I have the following code that uses a **List of string**  to get the email address first. Then I create a collection of email objects.

Is there a better way to avoid the redundant List and Collection using `LINQ`?

```
  Report report = new Report();
  report.Recipients   = "test@test.com, demo@demo.com";

  List<string> emailAddressList = new List<string>( report.Recipients.Split(',') );
  Collection<Email> emailObjectCollection = new Collection<Email>();

  foreach (string emailAddress in emailAddressList)
  {
           Email email = new Email();
           email.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
           emailObjectCollection.Add(email);
  }
```

**References**:

1. [Better code for avoiding one dictionary - Case Sensitivity Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247001/better-code-for-avoiding-one-dictionary-case-sensitivity-issue)
2. [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)
3. [Using LINQ to find duplicates across multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596604/using-linq-to-find-duplicates-across-multiple-properties)
4. [C#: Difference between List<T> and Collection<T> (CA1002, Do not expose generic lists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232108/c-difference-between-listt-and-collectiont-ca1002-do-not-expose-generic)

> **CA1002**: Do not expose generic lists. System.Collections.Generic.List is a generic collection designed for performance not inheritance and, therefore, does not contain any virtual members. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Why do you need to use `Collection<T>` at all? It's designed to be a *base* class... what advantage does it have for you over `List<T>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet  I need to return the collection in a publicly exposed method. If I use `List`, I will get `CA1002` warning in code analysis. Is it a bad idea to return a `Collection`? If yes, how should I modify the code to use collection in proper way?

Comment: @Lijo Just don't use `Collection` at all.  Create a `List` and return a `List`.

Comment: @Lijo Well, first off, it's just a warning, there is nothing to overcome.  Second, reading it's text, I disagree with what it's asserting; a `List` is a perfectly acceptable type to return, and obscuring it's type by exposing only a collection that provides no indication as to it's implementation is harmful to the caller; they won't know how to properly use the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a `HashSet`.

```
var emailObjectCollection = new HashSet<Email>(
     report.Recipients.Split(',').Select(e => new Email() { EmailAddress = e }));
```

Comment: Thanks. But why not collection?

Answer (score 4):

```
var  emailObjectCollection =   report.Recipients.Split(',')
                                    .Select(m=>new Email(){EmailAddress = m})
                                    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head:

```
var emailObjectCollection = new Collection<Email>(
    new List<string>(report.Recipients.Split(',')).Distinct()
        .Select<string, Email>(e => 
        {
            var email = new Email();
            email.EmailAddress = e;
        }).ToList());
```

That should be the LINQ-y way of populating a `Collection<T>` with unique values. Just curious though, why use a `Collection`? If you need to pass this enumerable around, would it not make more sense to use `IEnumerable`?

Plus, you *could* suppress the `CA1002` message with a suppression attribute - there are valid exceptions to the rule, from time to time (IMHO).