# What I m missing to implement case insensitive search?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, search, datatables

Here is my js file. I 've done everything in the server side. And implemented all basic and some advance feature of Datatable plugins. But the search function is case sensitive. If I search for "oil" it shows oil only but not OIL.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "/DB/AjaxOil",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "Search": {
        "caseInsensitive": true
              },
    "aoColumns": [
        {
            "sName": "OilId",
            "aTargets": [0],    //Edit column
            "mData": "OilId",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                var id = full[0]; //row id in the first column
                return "<a>"+id+"</a>";
            }
        },
        { "sName": "CommonName" },
        { "sName": "BotanicalName" },
        { "sName": "PlantParts" },
        { "sName": "Distillation" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [0],
            className: "hide_column",
            "searchable": false
        }
    ]

});
```

});

And Here is my ajax function

```
          public ActionResult AjaxOil(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        IEnumerable<Oil> allOils = _context.Oils.ToList();
        IEnumerable<Oil> filteredOils;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            filteredOils = allOils
                     .Where(c => c.CommonName.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                                 c.BotanicalName.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                                 c.PlantParts.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                 ||
                                 c.Distillation.Contains(param.sSearch));
        }
        else
        {
            filteredOils = allOils;
        }

        var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        Func<Oil, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 ? c.CommonName :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.BotanicalName :
                                                            c.PlantParts);


        var distillationFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_4"]);
        var commonFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_1"]);
        var botanicalFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_2"]);
        var plantFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_3"]);


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commonFilter))
        {
            filteredOils = filteredOils.Where(c => c.CommonName.Contains(commonFilter));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(botanicalFilter))
        {
            filteredOils = filteredOils.Where(c => c.BotanicalName.Contains(botanicalFilter));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(plantFilter))
        {
            filteredOils = filteredOils.Where(c => c.PlantParts.Contains(plantFilter));

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(distillationFilter))
        {
            filteredOils = filteredOils.Where(c => c.Distillation.Contains(distillationFilter));

        }


        var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"];
        if (sortDirection == "asc")
            filteredOils = filteredOils.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
        else
            filteredOils = filteredOils.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

        var displayedOils = filteredOils
                           .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
                           .Take(param.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedOils
                     select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.OilId), c.CommonName, c.BotanicalName, c.PlantParts, c.Distillation };
        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = allOils.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredOils.Count(),
            aaData = result
        },
                         JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

P.s. The database has 5million row so please suggest with performance point of view too.

Comment: Is this a dot net core app ? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Comment: Nope, but MVC 5. I think that is just for the test, which returns boolean  as result.

Comment: sorry I missed the depth of content. Thank you.

Comment: whats your database? Configuring it to do case insensitive search could be the best solution.

Comment: Mssql. yeah but again I 've some search option that should match perfectly. I need to know Working science else how can I learn more.

Comment: @Ujwal Neupane You could cache the results if you know the search will be executed multiple times and the datasource won't be changed in that period. You can also define 1 or more database indexes that can help to speed up the query. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/start-and-use-the-database-engine-tuning-advisor?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use `_context.Oils.ToList();` then you will retrieve all your records from the database before filtering them. If you place the `ToList()` after `.Take(param.iDisplayLength)` all your selection code will be translated to a query in your database and only the relevant records will be retrieved.  There is a difference between Contains executed by the Linq extension (case sensitve; see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947126/case-insensitive-list-search) SO question) and the Contains that will we translated by the Entity Framework to a LIKE SQL statement (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-mssql-server) SO question and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXhPn1TOvL4) video about tracing the SQL statements generated by your code).

Comment: If you place the ToList() after.Take(param.iDisplayLength) all your selection code will be translated to a query in your database and only the relevant records will be retrieved.
will you little elaborate. Please. I got with it display length but how to combine with search(upper and lower case is not problem here.)

Comment: I need to pick data that match the search and show only param.iDisplayLenght number of result. If i pick number of data at first then my search will be totally compermised.

Comment: See [this](https://anthonychu.ca/post/entity-framework-parameterize-skip-take-queries-sql/) article regarding the working of Skip and Take in Entity Framework.

Comment: Entity Framework will build all C# query statements before ToList() to 1 sql query. The order is important; for example, Skip(10).Take(5) is not the same as Take(5).Skip(10).

Comment: You open my eyes. I just forget the concept of thread actually. But it still takes 1.1 min for every request should I use the cache? I can't find the bottle neck.

Answer (score 1):

As Shyju mentioned, refer to this post:
[Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

This will give you a wholistic idea of what to expect.

Here is a small excerpt from the post for your reference:

> To test if the string `paragraph` contains the string `word` (thanks @QuarterMeister)
>
> `culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(paragraph, word, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0`
>
> Where `culture` is the instance of [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) describing the language that the text is written in.

**In addition**, I encourage you to visit this article which has an exhaustive comparison of various methods’ performances while checking if a string occurs within a string. This should help you decide what approach to take for better performance.

http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-occurs-within-a-string

Based on your question, you may have to create an extension method which will use different approach to preform check based on the type of input to achieve best performance.

Hope this helps!