# How to trim and convert to lower and compare between a list of string and a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, c#-4.0

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { " A ", "b" , "C"};

bool status = list.Contains(input);

I get the following status when I checked in console.

Case 1: string input = "A"; // false
Case 2: string input = "B"; // false
Case 3: string input = "C"; // true
Case 4: string input = "c "; // false 
Case 5: string input = " C"; // false
Case 2: string input = "b"; // true
```

I want everything to be true, hence decided to trim and also convert both to lower. I however, don't know what would be the order, first trim or first convert to lower. Also, I dont know how to do it for list, please help me.

**UPDATE**

found answer to part of my question. I can do input.ToLower().Trim();

But is it the right order? And how to do the same for list items in this example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947126/case-insensitive-list-search - use this answer and also add your call to Trim()

Comment: You can do `list.Select(s => s.Trim().ToLower()).Contains(input.ToLower())`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Contains Case Insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive)

Comment: The best is not to use `ToLower` at all but the overload with a comparer, pass `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. You can google "turkish i problem", it's also more efficient

Comment: @SeM: Thank you so much. May I ask why you didn't trim input? Also, why you have chosen first the trim and then to lower in the select?

Comment: @Learner: why you store them with spaces at all? You can remove them before you add them to the list.

Comment: @Rango Well you can trim input too if you needed. Well it's kind of feels natural to trim first to get your char, then lower it.

Comment: Perhaps if it’s not timed first possible format exception in some case as it tries to convert to lower the empty space and exception, that’s why want to trim first I thought?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
list = list.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower().Trim());
```

This should help you to convert all the elements in your list to lowercase and trim extra space. This will pass all the conditions where there is a lower case string and no white space. Hope this helps.