# Best way to loop through a list within a sub-loop

Tags: vb.net

First things first, I did a search before posting this question but the answers are so generic that I could not find anything similar to what I'm trying to do. I apologize in advance if this has been answered before and I did not find it.

[image: List definition]

I have a scenario where I already collected a large list of rows (>10K) from the SQL server and put into an array (List) of strings. These rows are consisted of filenames. Because I already put them on a list, I don't want to query the SQL server again and instead want work with what I already have in memory.

This is the code I'm trying to get right:

'Valid file types for InfoLink1, InfoLink2, InfoLink3

```
        Dim lstValidImageFormats As New List(Of String)({".JPG", ".JPEG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".PNG", ".TIF", ".TIFF", ".GIF"})
        Dim lstValidSTLFormats As New List(Of String)({".STL"})
        Dim lstValidSTEPFormats As New List(Of String)({".STP", ".STEP"})

        '////////////////
        '// Components //
        '////////////////

        'We don't check Parts.InfoLink because all formats are allowed in this field

        'Parts.InfoLink1 - File in Infolink1 columns MUST BE images

        For i = 0 To arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values.Count - 1 'We have 10K rows with filenames in this list
            For Each FileExtension As String In lstValidImageFormats
                If arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values.Item(i).EndsWith(FileExtension) = False Then


                End If
            Next

        Next
```

I'm trying to parse each item (filename) I have in the array `arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values`  and check if the filename DOES NOT end with one of the extensions in the list `lstValidImageFormats`. If it doesn't, then I'll send the filename to another list (array).

My difficulty here is about how to iterate through each item in `arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values`, then check if each filename ends with one of the extensions declared in `lstValidImageFormats`, do what I want to do with the item if it DOES NOT end with one of those extensions, and then proceed to parse the next item in `arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values`.

I sincerely don't know what's the best way/performance efficient to do that.

My code above is empty because algorithmically I don't know the best approach to do what I want without querying the SQL server again with something like `AND filename NOT LIKE '%.JPG' AND filename NOT LIKE '%.JPEG' AND filename NOT LIKE '%.JPE' AND filename NOT LIKE '%.BMP'...`

Because I already have the data in the memory in a list, performance would be much better if I could use what I already have.

Any suggestions or material I could read to learn how to do what I'm looking for?

Thank you!

Comment: Not seeing how this can help. What am I missing?

Comment: Something like `Dim newList = arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values.Where(Function(x) Not lstValidImageFormats.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(x))).ToList()`? You should probably do a [case-insensitive comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3947126/8967612) though.

Comment: @41686d6564 - That was what I've been looking for. An elegant solution! Thank you!

Comment: So databases have things like indexes that are _really good_ for putting data like this together. Thus the plan to load the entire dataset into memory is probably making things **slower** -- _much_ slower -- rather than speeding things up.

Comment: Anyway, the SQL solution would be to have another table with your valid file types, and then you do a `JOIN` to that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would tackle this:

```
Dim invalidFormatFiles = _
    From x In arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values _
    Let fi = New FileInfo(x) _
    Where Not lstValidImageFormats.Contains(fi.Extension.ToUpperInvariant()) _
    Select x

For Each invalidFormatFile In invalidFormatFiles
    ' Do your processing
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this and it worked:

```
Dim lstValidImageFormats As New List(Of String)({".JPG", ".JPEG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".PNG", ".TIF", ".TIFF", ".GIF"})
    Dim lstValidSTLFormats As New List(Of String)({".STL"})
    Dim lstValidSTEPFormats As New List(Of String)({".STP", ".STEP"})

    '////////////////
    '// Components //
    '////////////////

    'We don't check Parts.InfoLink because all formats are allowed in this field

    'Parts.InfoLink1 - File in Infolink1 columns MUST BE images

    Dim intExtCounter As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To arrIntComponentsInfolink1UNRs.Count - 1 'We have 10K rows with filenames in this list
        intExtCounter = 0
        For j = 0 To lstValidImageFormats.Count - 1
            If arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values.Item(i).EndsWith(lstValidImageFormats.Item(j)) = True Then
                intExtCounter += 1
            End If
        Next
        If intExtCounter = 0 Then 'At least one file extension was found
            arrIntComponentsInfolink1UNRsReportSectionInvalidExtensions.Add(i) 'File extension is not in the list of allowed extensions
        End If
    Next
```

But @41686d6564 answer was the best solution:

```
Dim newList = arrStrComponentsInfolink1Values.Where(Function(x) Not lstValidImageFormats.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(x))).ToList()
```

Thank you!